# VBA. Получить информацию с динамически созданной формы

Tags: vba

Динамически создается форма

```
Dim tmpForm As VBComponent
Dim tmpComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox, tmpBtn As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim selExp As Long

Set tmpForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
With tmpForm
    .Properties("Caption") = "Выберите пункт"
End With
Set tmpComboBox = tmpForm.Designer.Controls.add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With tmpComboBox
    .name = "tmpComboBox"
End With
Set tmpBtn = tmpForm.Designer.Controls.add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
With tmpBtn
    .Caption = "Выбрать"
    .name = "BtnChoose"
End With

With tmpForm.CodeModule
    .InsertLines 7, "Private Sub UserForm_Activate()"
    .InsertLines 8, "   With me.tmpComboBox"
    .InsertLines 9, "      .AddItem 1"
    .InsertLines 10, "     .AddItem 2"
    .InsertLines 11, "     .ListIndex = 0"
    .InsertLines 12, "   End With"
    .InsertLines 13, "End Sub"

    .InsertLines 20, "Private Sub BtnChoose_Click()"
    .InsertLines 22, "me.hide"
    .InsertLines 23, "End Sub"
End With

VBA.UserForms.add(tmpForm.name).Show
' Вот тут нужно как-то получить выбранное значение tmpComboBox
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.remove tmpForm

Set tmpComboBox = Nothing
Set tmpBtn = Nothing
Set tmpForm = Nothing
```

Каким образом можно получить выбранное значение tmpComboBox? Пробовал обращаться напрямую к `tmpComboBox`, но после запуска временной формы она уже ни на что не ссылается. Пробовал создавать `Public` переменную в форме - не знаю, как к ней обратиться, на любой запрос получаю ошибку, что tmpForm не содержит такого свойства. Хотел обратиться к семейству `Controls` формы, но у неё нет такого семейства.

Comment: Форма создана и открыта. Еще ничего не выбирали. После выбора запустить новую процедуру, реагирующую на изменение значения `tmpComboBox`. А вообще - почему не создать форму сразу и открывать готовую?

Comment: @vikttur в итоге сделал с отдельной формой, но интерес именно с динамически создаваемой. Дополнил вопрос своими действиями, которые не привели к нужному результату.

Comment: Вы открыли форму и тут же хотите получить значение *ComboBox*. Но ведь значения еще нет! Оно появится после выбора из выпадающего списка. `tmpComboBox.Value`  или  `tmpComboBox.Text`. Но не в процедуре создания формы.

Comment: @vikttur тут Вы не правы, форма запускается в строке `VBA.UserForms.add(tmpForm.name).Show` и забирает себе управление. В точку, в которой я хочу получить значение, программа попадает только после того, как форма вернет управление. В моём случае это делается нажатием на кнопку. В форме, в принципе, можно сделать, чтобы значение `tmpComboBox` сохранялось в какую-то Public переменную, объявленную в модуле, но хочется обойтись без них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось просто. Нужно найти эту форму в коллекции `VBA.UserForms`, в этом случае она уже будет обладать всеми свойствами обычных форм.

```
For i = 0 To VBA.UserForms.Count - 1
    If VBA.UserForms(i).Name = tmpForm.Name Then
        selExp = VBA.UserForms(i).choosenValue
    End If
Next i
```

Можно добавить к ней свойство, в которое сохранять и из которого получать нужное значение.

```
 .InsertLines 2, "Private formVar as Long"
 .InsertLines 3, "Property Get choosenValue() as Long"
 .InsertLines 4, "   choosenValue = formVar"
 .InsertLines 5, "End Property"
```

Окончательный код выглядит так

```
Dim tmpForm As VBComponent
Dim tmpComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox, tmpBtn As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim selExp As Long, i As Long

Set tmpForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
With tmpForm
    .Properties("Caption") = "Выберите пункт"
End With
Set tmpComboBox = tmpForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With tmpComboBox
    .Name = "tmpComboBox"
    .Top = 10
End With
Set tmpBtn = tmpForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
With tmpBtn
    .Caption = "Выбрать"
    .Name = "BtnChoose"
    .Top = 40
End With

With tmpForm.CodeModule
    .InsertLines 2, "Private formVar as Long"
    .InsertLines 3, "Property Get choosenValue() as Long"
    .InsertLines 4, "   choosenValue = formVar"
    .InsertLines 5, "End Property"
    .InsertLines 7, "Private Sub UserForm_Activate()"
    .InsertLines 8, "   With me.tmpComboBox"
    .InsertLines 9, "      .AddItem 1"
    .InsertLines 10, "     .AddItem 2"
    .InsertLines 11, "     .ListIndex = 0"
    .InsertLines 12, "   End With"
    .InsertLines 13, "End Sub"

    .InsertLines 20, "Private Sub BtnChoose_Click()"
    .InsertLines 21, "   formVar = me.tmpComboBox.value"
    .InsertLines 22, "   me.hide"
    .InsertLines 23, "End Sub"
End With

VBA.UserForms.Add(tmpForm.Name).Show
For i = 0 To VBA.UserForms.Count - 1
    If VBA.UserForms(i).Name = tmpForm.Name Then
        selExp = VBA.UserForms(i).choosenValue
    End If
Next i

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove tmpForm

Set tmpComboBox = Nothing
Set tmpBtn = Nothing
Set tmpForm = Nothing
```